# Correctly calling PMT function and the correct declaration of values

Tags: excel, finance, vba

I'm creating a subroutine for the user to enter through input boxes the relevant variables such as their age, target retirement age etc to come up with a savings plan.

```
Sub savings_target()

Dim Age As Double
Dim Target_Age As Double
Dim Annual_return As Long
Dim nper As Integer
Dim rate As Integer
Dim required_pmt As Variant

Age = (Val(InputBox("Enter your current age", "Curret age", "Enter your age here...")))
Target_Age = (Val(InputBox("Enter your target age for retirement", "Target Age", "Enter your target age of retirement here")))
Annual_return = (Val(InputBox("Enter your assumed annual return", "Assumed annual return", "Enter assumed annual return here")))

nper = (Target_Age - Age) * 12
rate = Annual_return / 12

required_pmt = Pmt(rate, nper, 0, -500000, 0)

MsgBox ("Your required montly savings payment is :" & " " & "$" & required_pmt)
Range("a1").Value = required_pmt


End Sub
```

However, hay errores when using the sub. When using the sub with the following amounts age: 25, target age:70, annual return 5% the value of monthly savings plan is: $925.9259
However, when i use the excel worksheet pmt function with the same values (and 1 fv of -500000) the value is different ($246.74)

I'm wondering if the VBA PMT function is called correctly, or if the declaration of the variables is affecting it. For example, if you change Dim rate as interger to Dim rate as double, it returns a very different value.

Thanks

Comment: You need to declare `Annual_return` and `rate` as `Double.  When declared as integer they round to `0`.  You would have seen this if you steped through your code and examined the intermediate values at each step.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I've tried them as doubles and stepped through. The locals show as - Age- 25, Target Age, 70, nper 540, rate as 0.41667. This results in an answer of required_pmt as 4.307 E-77, so it's even further away from the correct answer...

Comment: _rate as 0.41667_ : that's 41% per month!  Surely you meant `Annual_return  = 0.041667`

Comment: @chrisneilsen, wow, lost for words a bit, quite embarrassing. Yes, you are correct thank you!!